# Is it possible to create extension operators in C#?

Tags: c#

So the basic idea was:

We have some business model

```
public class Model
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And it's view model representation

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator ViewModel(Model b)
    {
        // Map instances using AutoMapper or whatever
        return new ViewModel { Foo = b.Foo.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Our basic instinct is to map model to view model. As you can see I want to perform mapping using `explicit operator` so I could do

```
var model = new Model { Foo = 42 }; // Get model
var viewModel = (ViewModel)model;   // Map to view model
```

and therefore have my controller code as clean as possible... **BUT** I want to make view model and mapping logic stay separated. How can I move `explicit operator` implementation to some external class? Similar to extension methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static explicit operator ViewModel(Model b)
    {
        // Map instances using Automapper or whatever
        return new ViewModel { Foo = b.Foo.ToString() };
    }
}
```

This code, obviously, isn't compiling because of two reasons:
*- Static classes can not contain user-defined operators

- Either parameter or return type must be Extensions*

Also, as an option, I could make view model partial and split model itself and operator to separate *.cs* files but it would not make the case. Architecturally they would still be the same class in the same namespace. I want to be able to implement mapping logic, for example, in another project in solution.

I just want to achieve similar to extension methods effect. How can I do that?

Comment: One idea coming to mind is: Make your ViewModel a partial class and there you have separate files for the mapping and the model itself.

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure that's not possible to do with extension methods. You can make a partial class and have a normal overloaded operator if you just want to separate the logic, though.

Comment: This would be horrible to program with. Can you imagine if the addition operator behavior changed depending on what namespaces you reference? Ugly!

Comment: @BitTickler better yet, a separate class for the mapping the `ViewModel` to `Model`. The view model then uses the mapping class.

Comment: @Gusdor You said this right at the time I was contemplating that there are already too many classes in this approach. The pattern we see here would be "Model View Model Controller View" (MVMCV)? :) Maybe removing a few classes might be possible, using some closures instead? Given that all the ViewModel seems to do is mapping an int to a string...

Comment: @BitTickler, see my updates ... I've already considered that option.

Comment: @BitTickler personally, I'd rather have lots of small classes with very defined behavior. For mapping one string it probably isn't appropriate - I assumed this was a trivial example of a more complex problem.

Comment: @Gusdor Especially the nontrivial cases trouble me. Imagine 200 properties in model. And model changing. Do you really like the idea to create 200 *eager* mappings each time 1 property changes?

Comment: @BitTickler the problem here is not in the amount of properties and mapping process itself (for mapping can be used automation tools like AutoMapper) but the ability to place mapping logic outside `ViewModel` class but inside `explicit operator`. The more I say it the more impossible it sounds.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing better than just:

```
public class ModelToViewModelMapper
{
    public ViewModel Map(Model b)
    {
        return new ViewModel { Foo = b.Foo.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Extension methods can do the same work, but what if you want to change the mapping logic. It will be easy if you use dependency injection and non-static classes

Comment: If one imagines the model to have 200 properties instead of 1, this does not look very attractive anymore, does it?

Comment: @BitTickler I see no alternatives. You can sacrifice flexibility and invent a common mechanism for any property, but cases where it worth doing that are too specific.

Comment: Yes, this is nice, thanks for trying to help, that's why I give you +1, but, as I already said to BitTickler - the problem here is not in the mapping process itself but the ability to place mapping logic outside `ViewModel` class but inside `explicit operator`. The more I say it the more impossible it sounds.

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi Even if would be possible (in the way you described it), I'd recommend against it. Explicit cast is just a sugar around static method. It reduces your code size but lacks extensibility.

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi Why would code size differ between the 2 cases under discussion (operator function or named function)? The implementation inside would be exactly the same, right?

Comment: @BitTickler they would be, right. But still my question is more about extension operators than mapping, this is just for example, as one of the possibilities of using extension operators.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it the way *MS* does it in the `System.Linq` namespace; there is tons of type conversions that are done through extension methods (you can't do it with operators, C# does not support extension operators).

Define the following extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{    
    public static ViewModel ToViewModel(this Model model) {...}
}
```

I think the code remains clean enough which seems to be your primary goal here.